# CHEF / knife - running shell script

Tags: bash, chef-infra, knife

I'm using a script to collect build spec information from the user, then using knife to clone and build a VM to spec.  CHEF then copies some shell scripts to the provisioned node, then I execute those scripts using "knife ssh".

This works fine:

```
template '/path/to/filename.sh' do
  source 'filename.sh.erb'
  mode 755
end
```

This doesn't:

```
cookbook_file '/path/to/filename.sh' do
  source 'filename.sh'
  mode 755
end
```

The contents of the filename.sh.erb and filename.sh are identical.  The error message I get is as follows:

**DEMO-CCM2.t3fca.com bash: /tmp/C3_Component_Install.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

The very top of both files looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

If I go to the host and try to run the script manually, all of the following work just fine:

- sh C3_Component_Install.sh
- /bin/bash C3_Component_Install.sh
- /usr/bin/bash C3_Component_Install.sh
- /tmp/C3_Component_Install.sh

So I don't know what's wrong.    Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the file with Windows newlines, which cookbook_file recreated for you while the template fixed during processing. If you save using Unix newlines it would be the same.

Comment: I'm using Atom on Windows, saving files into shared directory with Vagrant instance so I can execute Chef code from within Vagrant instance (CentOS 7).  Are you saying that if instead of saving files through Atom, I copied the text into my clipboard, and then pasted it into 'nano' (text editor) in my terminal emulator into the Vagrant instance that this would not resolve my issue?  Is there a way to resolve my issue except for doing all of my text editing natively in Linux?  Or is the only solution to stick with the templates method?  What about templates fixes this?  Thanks.

Comment: Atom includes the line-ending-selector plugin by default AFAIK, see https://github.com/atom/line-ending-selector for a screenshot. Make that `LF`.